How do you specify all uses of systemd service unit template in journalctl?
I have a systemd servie unit template that takes arguments: my.service.unit@.service. I call it with:
systemctl start my.service.unit@argument.service

But I can't figure out how to call any use of my template in the journalctl logs without specifying SyslogIdentifier in the unit file and using journalctl SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=my.identifier -n10.  This seems a tiny bit hacky to me.  Is there a better way?
I've tried:
journalctl _SYSTEMD_UNIT=my.service.unit@.service -n10

but no luck.

Does journalctl -u 'my.service.unit@*.service' work?

It did work, but was horribly slow.  I suppose because of the wildcard.  I thought _SYSTEMD_UNIT and -u was equivalent but journalctl _SYSTEMD_UNIT='my.service.unit@*.service' didn't work.  So strange.  Thanks.

You could restrict journalctl to the current boot (uptime) by using the -b 0 option. Much faster. @mutu 's command searches the logs since the beginning of time.

I was using it with -n10 and it still took a second.  It is instant usually.  I also just tried -b0.

If you want fast access to your logs you can use a separate journal, see man systemd-journald.service. Simply invent a name and add it to the unit
file:
[Service]
LogNamespace=myspace

To see the logs specify the name in the journalctl command with any other
options:
journalctl --namespace=myspace

This is implemented by a mount namespace created on demand through the
systemd-journald@.service template.
systemctl status systemd-journald@myspace.service shows it is triggered by:
TriggeredBy: * systemd-journald@myspace.socket
             * systemd-journald-varlink@myspace.socket

The first socket receives the syslog output and so on from your unit, and
the second socket is used by the journalctl command, I believe.
There is no need to start or stop these services and sockets explicitly.
The systemd-journald process started when the sockets are opened is
deactivated after 30 seconds of non-use.
The log files are kept under /var/log/journal/*.myspace/ and if wanted
you can configure the space they need and so on by creating
/etc/systemd/journald@myspace.conf.
